# Is there a generic word for young livestock?

Tags: animals, agriculture

So I am looking for a generic word for calf, lamb, chick, kid, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `young` as a noun here: *cow's young*, *deer with her young*, *keeping young with their mothers*. However, it is usually restricted to plural usage, though some do use it for individual animals.

If you wish to be a bit more official/bookish/scientific, the proper terms are `offspring` and `progeny` (the last one is also restricted to plural usage).